# Tapestry BeanEditForm customisation

Tags: forms, field, overriding, tapestry, templating

I am starting a new project using Tapestry 5.x. To get confortable with it I am doing a few expermiment.

For now I am looking for a way to add a little star as the fist element of the label of every field of a form with a "required" constraint of the rendered entity.

For example

```
public class Address
{
    @Validate("required")
    public String lastName;
}
```

Rendered with

```
<t:beaneditform object="addr" submitlabel="message:submit-label" />
```

Should render a html like

```
<div>
   <label><span>*</span> First name : </label>
   <input type="text" name="firstname" />
</div>
```

I currently have a code base really close to the one described in [the official documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/using-beaneditform-to-create-user-forms.html).

But sadly I haven't found a generic way to implement what I want.

Does any have an advice for me on this one ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a [Label](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Label.html) mixin. The mixin would use the following to get a reference to the label's `field` parameter.

```
@BindParameter
private Field field;
```

You could then test for `field.isRequired()` in you mixin and tweak the html. More info in mixins [here](http://tapestry.apache.org/component-mixins.html)

Once your mixin is working, you could then attach it to every label (even the ones inside BeanEditForm) using a [ComponentClassTransformWorker2](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/services/transform/ComponentClassTransformWorker2.html) as detailed in the blog post [here](https://tawus.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/tapestry-mixins-classtransformations/).